# Non-selective query against large data type where query is matching one record

Tags: apex, trigger

The system is throwing a non-selective query QueryException when trying to create a single Opportunity through the web UI - I understand what the (pleasantly verbose) exception means, but in this case, the problem query should only be returning one Account (as one Account ID is in the set and customerNumbers is empty), so I'm hoping another set of eyes can see what's going wrong.

---

[image]

---

```
public class OpportunityTriggerHandler {
    public static void handleCustomerNumbers(List<Opportunity> newRecs) {
        Set<Id> accountIDs = new Set<Id>();
        Set<String> customerNumbers = new Set<String>();
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        for (Opportunity o : newRecs) {
            accountIDs.add(o.Customer_Name__c);
            customerNumbers.add(o.Customer_Number__c);
        }

        // ************************************************************
        // this query is generating the exception**********************
        // ************************************************************
        Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<ID, Account>([SELECT 
            Id, ParentId, Parent.Name, Customer__c,
            BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode
            FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIDs OR Customer__c IN :customerNumbers]);

        Map<String, Account> customerNumberAccountMap = new Map<String, Account>();
        for (Account a : accountMap.values()) {
            customerNumberAccountMap.put(a.Customer__c, a);
        }

        for (Opportunity oo : newRecs) {
            if (oo.Customer_Number__c != accountMap.get(oo.Customer_Name__c).Customer__c) {
                if (customerNumberAccountMap.get(oo.Customer_Number__c) != null) {
                    oo.Customer_Name__c = customerNumberAccountMap.get(oo.Customer_Number__c).id;
                }
                else {
                    accountMap.get(oo.Customer_Name__c).Customer__c = oo.Customer_Number__c;
                    accountsToUpdate.add(accountMap.get(oo.Customer_Name__c));
                }
            }
        }
        update accountsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception isn't complaining about the number of rows returned, it's complaining about the number of rows that it needs to search through in order to find that row. In your case I'm guessing Customer__c is not an indexed field? You could try marking it as an external ID which will make it indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception isn't complaining about the number of rows returned, it's complaining about the number of rows that it needs to search through in order to find that row. In your case I'm guessing Customer__c is not an indexed field? You could try marking it as an external ID which will make it indexed.

Edit: We solved the issue by changing the `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE Id IN :accountIDs OR (Customer__c != null AND Customer__c IN :customerNumbers)
```

**Further edit**
As you say, you have a lot of account rows with null customer__c, so the query

```
Select id from account where customer__c = null
```

would not be "selective". Meaning it returns too high a % of the rows.

When you are populating your query lists, you are doing this

```
customerNumbers.add(o.Customer_Number__c);
```

Which is adding null to the list of Customer__c values that you will query

And this is causing your query to be non-selective.
You could avoid adding the value to the list in the first place

```
if (o.Customer_Number__c != null) customerNumbers.add(o.Customer_Number__c)
```

Comment: I changed the WHERE clause to `WHERE Id IN :accountIDs OR (Customer__c != null AND Customer__c IN :customerNumbers)` and it's now working...we realized there were many Accounts with Customer__c values of null. But your answer makes me question whether what we suspected was the cause was truly the cause

Comment: I'll accept your answer once I'm allowed to - but I want to understand exactly why adding the null check on Customer__c fixed the problem. Was it because it eliminated the need for indexing the field, or was it because originally the query was trying to return all the rows for which Customer__c was null?

Comment: I've updated the answer, basically the "or" part of your original query was trying to search for every account with null customer__c and that was outside the limits of what is a selective query.

Comment: Got it - makes total sense. Thanks for your time and help!